# Troubles with Boolean values, of Trigger type (SmartTarget, Tridion 9)

Tags: smarttarget, sites-9, experience-optimization

[image: Screen-shot of promotion's trigger.]
I'm experiencing some difficulties with Trigger Type (Smart-Target; "SDL Tridion Sites 9").
When I create a trigger type, and set its value to be string, and pass a claim (as a string), everything works as expected.
Similar happens, with numeric values. Therefore, I believe we can assume, that configuration is ok ("cd_ambient_conf.xml" and "smartarget_conf.xml").

The problem occurs with Boolean values. I set trigger type to receive Boolean values. And I pass a Boolean value (from my web-app), as a claim, but the promotion doesn't get triggered...

Samples of PowerShell and C# pieces of code, respectively:

```
PS C:\> Get-XoTriggerType -id 'id_of_trigger'

Id          : id_of_trigger
Name        : Title of trigger
UrlParam    : trigger_url
BaseType    : Boolean
MultiSelect : False
Values      : {True, False}
```

This is my cmdlet, for creating new (Boolean) Trigger type:

```
PS C:\> new-xoTriggerType -Id 'id_of_trigger' -Name 'Title of trigger' -UrlParam 'trigger_url' -BaseType Boolean -Values True, False
```

And C#:

```
AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Put(
    new Uri("taf:claim:trigger:url"), true, ClaimValueScope.Session
);
```

Did anyone else face such scenario?
Or, do I do something wrong?

(Sorry, if I misbehave, I'm still a bit new.)

## Edit:

I've attached a screen-shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was confirmed by SDL support as a defect and we are awaiting a hotfix. I will edit this question once the hotfix is available with its details.

edit: hotfix CD_11.0.0.17035 resolves this issue

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is in the values you are passing into New-XoTriggerType.

Technically, you are passing in the strings "True" and "False" which aren't actual Boolean values. Try using "$true" and "$false" instead, as those are the Boolean values in PowerShell.

```
PS C:\> New-XoTriggerType -Id 'id_of_trigger' -Name 'Title of trigger' -UrlParam 'trigger_url' -BaseType Boolean -Values $true,$false
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've tried, but no luck.
(Old trigger-type is removed. New one is created, relying on suggested syntax. In promotion, new trigger-type is added. Web-app is re-started. But, promotion doesn't get hit, still...)